# I cannot add a reference in Visual Studio Mac

Tags: c#, visual-studio-mac

When I right click references only Refresh and Edit References come up and if I go to edit references it just shows the ones there but I cant add any. When I open edit references there is All, Packages, Projects and .NET Assembly. Im trying to add a .NET assembly reference.

Comment: This might be of help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41789971/how-to-add-reference-to-assembly-in-visual-studio-mac

Comment: Already looked and didnt seem to work for me.

Comment: What sort of project are you trying? There are some problems with Android projects currently.

Answer (score 0):

If you are still looking for the answer to this.

1. Right click on your solution (Two fingers on track pad and click)
2. Display options
3. Click "Show all files"
4. Then you'll see projectname.csproj

You can edit it.