# Razor View to PDF in .Net with IronPDF

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, pdf-generation

Am trying to render a Razor View to PDF with the help of [IronPDF](https://ironpdf.com/docs/questions/razor-view-to-pdf/#helpscout-support), so I was using this method to first convert the Razor View to a string then later I render it as a PDF, but class `ViewEngine` is not resolved in the `RenderRazorViewToString()` method, what could be done here :

```
public string RenderRazorViewToString(string viewName, object model)
        {
            ViewData.Model = model;
            using (var sw = new StringWriter())
            {


                var viewResult = ViewEngine.Engines.FindPartialView(ControllerContext,
                    viewName);
                var viewContext = new ViewContext(ControllerContext, viewResult.View,
                    ViewData, TempData, sw);
                viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);
                viewResult.ViewEngine.ReleaseView(ControllerContext, viewResult.View);
                return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Having done this *exact* same thing, but with a different PDF converter... you'll need to include `System.Web.Mvc` :)

[image: Adding a Reference to <code>System.Web.Mvc</code>]

Comment: Do you have red squiggly lines under the `using` statement? Is it the same error message?

Comment: Yes there's a red line under that `using`, actually `Mvc` is the one not resolved.

Comment: Add `System.Web.Mvc` as a reference.  It's in "Assemblies -> Extensions"

Comment: Ok let med do this.

Comment: Am using VS mac, can guide me on how to add them, I seem not to see where the assemblies are.

Comment: @IdrisStack I'm afraid I can't help you there, as I do not use a Mac.  does this answer help?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41789971/how-to-add-reference-to-assembly-in-visual-studio-mac

Comment: I'm also trying to do the same thing. I still cannot get the error of of ViewEngine even though I have `using System.Web.Mvc;` : EDIT: I just found a ViewEngines and I believe IronPDF may have a typo on its tutorial

Comment: Not an IronPDF problem we just both made the same typo